# Installing Atom text editor on 32-bit Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, compatibility, atom

The [Atom](http://atom.io/) text editor, newly introduced by the GitHub team, looks like **"a hackable text editor for the 21st Century"**, and I must say, the screenshots have lured me. Official binaries are only available for OS X. After going open-source many have created their own binaries, and some even added them to repos. But when reading a tutorial on installation I read this:

> Currently Atom only works on 64-bit (on Linux) so if you use Ubuntu
>   32-bit, you can't install it by using this PPA and not even by
>   compiling it for yourself.

So is there any way to install it on Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit? Maybe 64-bit emulation or something?

Comment: Sorry. I don't think so. The world is moving to 64bit. If your CPU supports 64bit architecture, you are highly advised to upgrade to 64bit Ubuntu *regardless of how much of RAM you have*

Comment: I guess the 21st century doesn't use 32 bit machines... :(

Comment: @Naveen And how do I know my machine supports 64bit architecture? Google has been unwilling to offer a way.

Comment: Atom is now released for 32bit: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/atom-text-editor-available-for-linux.html

Comment: @Naveen Finally! Ohhhh yeah!

Answer (score 22):

Atom text editor is currently available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu from the Atom text editor PPA with different builds for 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. Atom text editor can be installed from the terminal by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

The current version of Atom text editor from ppa:webupd8team/atom updated to Ubuntu 16.04/16.10/17.04/17.10 is <s>1.0.10</s> 1.22.1.

For more information about Atom text editor visit the [official Atom website](https://atom.io/). A .deb file for installing Atom text editor is currently available from the official Atom website. but only for 64-bit operating systems. To install Atom text editor from the official Atom website on 32-bit Ubuntu follow the instructions in the accepted answer to [How I can create a 32-bit version of Atom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641239/how-i-can-create-a-32-bit-version-of-atom).

There is currently an Atom text editor snap package that can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu using the command `sudo snap install --classic atom` however the Atom snap package is only available for 64-bit OSs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to run 64bit binaries on 32bit hardware (that i'm aware of).
I couldn't even install a 64bit operating system in Virtualbox on my 32bit laptop.

But if you only want 32bit Atom text editor:

> Linux build is currently 64bit-only, because we only have 64bit libchromiumcontent and atom-shell on Linux for now.

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1814#issuecomment-42318420

I think we can expect a 32bit version some time soon.

Your cpu is 32bit if in 'cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep flags' there's no 'lm' listed.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/atom-text-editor-available-for-linux.html