# How to compile GitHub's Atom editor

Tags: compiling, arm, atom

I'm trying to install [GitHub's Atom editor](https://github.com/atom/atom). I'm using Ubuntu (trusty 14.04 with LXDE) on my Chromebook (via [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)). It has an ARM processor (not Intel or AMD) so I can't use the .deb because that's built for Intel architecture.

I've attempted to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md) but cannot seem to get it to compile. Using the Terminal, how can I compile Atom?

**Update: The errors I am getting**

Following [these instructions](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md), I can get to step 3 but when I type `script/build` I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I cloned atom into `/home/username/atom` if that helps.

**Update 2**

Thanks to the comments below I was able to start the build process. Unfortunately, I'm now getting the following errors:

```
gyp: name 'chromeos' is not defined while evaluating condition 'target_arch=="arm" and chromeos==1' in deps/breakpad/breakpad.gyp while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.11
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/henrywright/atom/build/node_modules/minidump
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

Does anyone know how to solve these errors?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Related question: [Installing Atom text editor on 32-bit Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468359/installing-atom-text-editor-on-32-bit-ubuntu), see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468359/installing-atom-text-editor-on-32-bit-ubuntu/558751#558751) about how to easily install a prebuilt and up-to-date Debian package of Atom Text Editor from the webupd8team/atom PPA for Atom text editor.

Comment: @muru I've updated my question with the error I'm getting and the steps I took to get there. Hope you can help?

Comment: Thanks @karel for the link, I'd still like to try to compile myself as I need to understand how it's done.

Comment: @henrywright I imagine that's because the `node` program in Debian-based systems is called `nodejs` - see the second answer in the post linked above on how to make it be called `node`.

Comment: It also says in the instructions for Ubuntu that you linked to in your question as follows: *Make sure the command node is available after Node.js installation (some systems [e.g. Ubuntu] install it as nodejs).*

Comment: Right! Thanks @muru I'll check out that answer. Looks like that could be the issue.

Comment: @karel it sure does, thanks for pointing that out. Was an error on my part for assuming the node command was available

Comment: @muru and karel, I made it to the script/build stage thanks to you. But am now getting new errors. I've updated my question with them.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/atom/node-minidump/issues/5

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Sorry for the basic question but where would I find `~/.gyp/include.gypi`? I'm a noob to using the terminal.

Comment: @muru Please ping me in chat if/when you get around to posting an answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: @henrywright That is the full path (`~` is your home folder). If it doesn't exist, I think you can create it: `mkdir -p ~/.gyp`, `gedit ~/.gyp/include.gypi`.

Comment: Thanks. I've now hit another error so have raised a support issue on their GitHub repo. See [here](https://github.com/atom/node-minidump/issues/8). Thanks again for your help.