# How I can create a 32-bit version of Atom?

Tags: compiling, 32-bit, atom

The new [Atom 1.0](https://atom.io/) text editor is now available. But only to 64-bit processors. How I can create a 32-bit version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These [instructions](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md) assume you have a 32-bit system:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libgnome-keyring-dev fakeroot rpm libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev
```

Setup `node.js`:

```
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Clone the Atom repository:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/atom/atom
```

If you need the latest release:

```
git fetch -p
git checkout $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
```

Now build and install:

```
cd atom
sudo script/build --create-debian-package
```

Use `sudo` above to avoid *permission denied* errors during the build process. Also, if you have a problem at the `build` command, run `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10`.

---

Or install Atom via a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

Comment: script/build give me that error: http://i.imgur.com/f7UFbVK.png

Comment: Same here with another Atom plugin. Try it again later. It's a temporary problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe an other server in the latest Atom release for the plugins. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I've now the `.deb` 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md

Build it mate. As it is in readme, step by step. :)

Answer (score 0):

A 32 bit version of Atom [is now availible](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/atom-text-editor-available-for-linux.html).

Run the following commands to add its repository and install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```