# Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit

Tags: 12.04, microsoft

I've downloaded and installed the deb and the bin package for Visual Studio Code 32bit, but in both cases I'm getting the following error when I try to start it

```
./code: line 36: 2704 Illegal instruction   ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
```

I can't understand what is causing this problem. My system release is 12.04.5 LTS

### With gdebi

Same error, see my LXTerminal from LXDE

```
mirko@localhost:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi code_1.6.1-1476372351_i386.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 


Code editing. Redefined.
 Visual Studio Code is a new choice of tool that combines the simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for the core edit-build-debug cycle. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux for installation instructions and FAQ.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 97473 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking code (from code_1.6.1-1476372351_i386.deb) ...
Setting up code (1.6.1-1476372351) ...

mirko@localhost:~/Downloads$ code
/usr/bin/code: line 36:  5907 Illegal instruction     ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
```

### Current status: still Open issue

Please note that, despite the accepted answer, the issue is still open

From Microsoft [VSCode GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14724), they asked me to file an issue to [Electron GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7808).
I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Is it Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: I believe that you are trying to install Visual Studio Code because Visual Studio can only be installed in Windows !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to completely remove both Atom and Visual Studio Code(even the configuration files) because they both run on Electron framework and it seems that there is some problem with it. Also remove the installers you used to install them. Then install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) in your system. Then download installer(.deb packages) of Visual Studio Code(32-bit) and install it. To install Atom(32-bit), go to the link given below and follow the instructions there :-

[How I can create a 32-bit version of Atom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641239/how-i-can-create-a-32-bit-version-of-atom)

Hope it works !

If it still doesn't work, file an issue at [Electron GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues)

Comment: Don't run "code" from Downloads folder! First type cd to go to /home/mirko and then type "code" there!

Comment: I mean do like this :- `mirko@localhost:~$ code`

Comment: Search for "Visual Studio Code" from Dash in Ubuntu! Is it present there ?

Comment: OK! Check whether Code is in **Installed Applications**

Comment: If it is there, try to run it from there !

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Because both VS Code and Atom run on Electron framework!

Comment: I suggest you to remove/uninstall  both Atom and VS Code completely. Even remove the packages(.deb/.tar.gz) you used to install Atom and VS Code.

Comment: Then download the installers(.deb packages) of Atom and VS Code one-by-one and install them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47711/discussion-between-gautam-vashisht-and-go-functional).

Comment: Read this link to install node - https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nodejs/node-js-npm-install-ubuntu/

Comment: Has your issue got resolved or not ?