# Building Atom from source fails with error referring to folder I can't find, even on github

Tags: software-installation, atom

I've been having trouble installing Atom, every version, every method. I've tried installing Atom by initiating through Ubuntu Software, and that's a no go. The button changes to show a progress bar, then immediately goes back to saying 'Install.' I've tried the install packages for a number of releases, from the newest version, back about 5 or 6. And I've tried building from source, but this isn't working either. I've followed the install instructions and set everything up, but when I run the 'script/build' command, I get this:

```
XXXXX@XXXXX-XXXXX:~/atom$ sudo script/build
[sudo] password for XXXXX: 
Node:   v6.11.2
Npm:    v5.3.0
Installing script dependencies
Installing apm
npm ERR! path /home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors' -> '/home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansicolors.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/XXXXX/.npm/_logs/2017-09-05T16_27_02_383Z-debug.log
child_process.js:495
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: /home/XXXXX/atom/script/node_modules/.bin/npm --global-style --loglevel=error install
npm ERR! path /home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansicolors' -> '/home/XXXXX/atom/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansicolors.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/XXXXX/.npm/_logs/2017-09-05T16_27_02_383Z-debug.log

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:472:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:492:13)
    at module.exports (/home/XXXXX/atom/script/lib/install-apm.js:9:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXXXX/atom/script/bootstrap:29:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

I checked the github page to see if there's a folder that I'm missing, but there are only 2 files and no folders in the 'apm' folder on github. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the save problem when I was trying build Atom for 32-bit Ubuntu version. Fortunately, you can install Atom via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

Source: [Installing Atom text editor on 32-bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468359/installing-atom-text-editor-on-32-bit-ubuntu#558751)
Also, you can check current available for installation version via PPA here (thanks to [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek)): https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/atom

Comment: I would encourage you to[edit] your post and  add a source for this. Perhaps https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/atom